# « Défense » contre « interdiction »

Tags: usage, synonymes

[image]

Quelle serait la différence dans le sens si, au lieu de *Défense*, le nom *Interdiction* était employé (l'autre consigne demeurant la même) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aucune. Interdire c'est défendre de... http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/interdire
Il n'y a pas de différence de sens, par contre il y a des emplois préférés : "le fruit défendu", "la cité interdite", etc.